Why might LazyServiceProvider not be injected onto AbpDbContext in tests?
I've got a single layer abp.io project, v8.3.4.
I've have reconstructed the test harness, since this seems to be provided only when you generate a layered app.  I'm trying to avoid that (the layered part) as this is a simple project and I don't need that level of complexity.
I'm having trouble running tests that use my own DB context.
The context isn't registered, despite me doing so:
    private void ConfigureEfCore(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
    {
        // This should register the DbContext and the repositories
        context.Services.AddAbpDbContext<CameraControlDbContext>(options =>
        {
            /* create default repositories only for aggregate roots
             * Documentation: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Entity-Framework-Core#add-default-repositories
             */
            options.AddDefaultRepositories(includeAllEntities: true);
        });

        Configure<AbpDbContextOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Configure(configurationContext => { configurationContext.UseSqlite(options => { }); });
        });
    }

Yet when I run the test, during SeedTestData() it throws:

    .... <lots of stuf> ...
    
    
    Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException
    The requested service 'WFT.CameraControl.Data.CameraControlDbContext' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.


I should add that the app itself runs just fine.

I've verified that .AddAbpDbContext<>() is called.
There's only a single AbpModule in the test DLL  (listed below)
I'm configuring the SQLLite DB after having done the 'normal app' registration of the db context. And in this case, since the code isn't actually using the REAL app's module, I've explicitly configured the AbpDbContextOptions to UseSqlLite

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Here is my db context:

    using AppAny.Quartz.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
    using AppAny.Quartz.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.PostgreSQL;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Volo.Abp.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Volo.Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Modeling;
    using Volo.Abp.AuditLogging.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Volo.Abp.BlobStoring.Database.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Volo.Abp.Data;
    using Volo.Abp.DependencyInjection;
    using Volo.Abp.FeatureManagement.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Volo.Abp.Identity;
    using Volo.Abp.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Volo.Abp.OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Volo.Abp.PermissionManagement.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Volo.Abp.SettingManagement.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Volo.Abp.TenantManagement;
    using Volo.Abp.TenantManagement.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using WFT.CameraControl.Entities;
    
    namespace WFT.CameraControl.Data;
    
    [ReplaceDbContext(typeof(IIdentityDbContext))]
    [ReplaceDbContext(typeof(ITenantManagementDbContext))]
    [ConnectionStringName("Default")]
    public class CameraControlDbContext : AbpDbContext<CameraControlDbContext>, ITenantManagementDbContext,
        IIdentityDbContext
    {
        public const string DbTablePrefix = "App";
        public const string DbSchema = null;
    
        #region Entities from the modules
    
        /* Notice: We only implemented IIdentityProDbContext and ISaasDbContext
         * and replaced them for this DbContext. This allows you to perform JOIN
         * queries for the entities of these modules over the repositories easily. You
         * typically don't need that for other modules. But, if you need, you can
         * implement the DbContext interface of the needed module and use ReplaceDbContext
         * attribute just like IIdentityProDbContext and ISaasDbContext.
         *
         * More info: Replacing a DbContext of a module ensures that the related module
         * uses this DbContext on runtime. Otherwise, it will use its own DbContext class.
         */
    
        // Identity
        public DbSet<IdentityUser> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<IdentityClaimType> ClaimTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrganizationUnit> OrganizationUnits { get; set; }
        public DbSet<IdentitySecurityLog> SecurityLogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<IdentityLinkUser> LinkUsers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<IdentityUserDelegation> UserDelegations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<IdentitySession> Sessions { get; set; }
    
        // Tenant Management
        public DbSet<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TenantConnectionString> TenantConnectionStrings { get; set; }
    
        #endregion
    
        // The sites, cameras and doors that are being monitored for this tenant
        public DbSet<Site> Sites { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Camera> Cameras { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OpenableResource> OpenableResources { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CameraSession> CameraSessions { get; set; }
    
        public CameraControlDbContext(DbContextOptions<CameraControlDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("CameraControlDbContext created");
        }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    
            /* Include modules to your migration db context */
    
            builder.ConfigurePermissionManagement();
            builder.ConfigureSettingManagement();
            builder.ConfigureBackgroundJobs();
            builder.ConfigureAuditLogging();
            builder.ConfigureFeatureManagement();
            builder.ConfigureIdentity();
            builder.ConfigureOpenIddict();
            builder.ConfigureTenantManagement();
            builder.ConfigureBlobStoring();
    
            // ConfigureQuartzTables(builder);
    
            /* Configure your own entities here */
            builder.Entity<Site>(b =>
            {
                b.ToTable("WFT_Sites", DbSchema);
                b.ConfigureByConvention();
    
                b.HasMany(s => s.Cameras).WithOne(c => c.Site);
                b.HasMany(s => s.OpenableResources).WithOne(o => o.Site);
                b.ApplyObjectExtensionMappings();
            });
    
            builder.Entity<Camera>(b =>
            {
                b.ToTable("WFT_Cameras", DbSchema);
                b.ConfigureByConvention();
    
                b.HasMany<CameraAction>(ca => ca.Actions)
                    .WithOne(a => a.Camera)
                    .HasForeignKey(ca => ca.Id);
    
                b.HasIndex(c => c.CameraIdentifier).IsUnique();
                b.ApplyObjectExtensionMappings();
            });
    
            builder.Entity<CameraAction>(b =>
            {
                b.ToTable("WFT_CameraActions", DbSchema);
                b.ConfigureByConvention();
    
                b.HasOne<Camera>().WithMany(c => c.Actions);
                b.ApplyObjectExtensionMappings();
            });
    
            builder.Entity<OpenableResource>(b =>
            {
                b.ToTable("WFT_OpenableResources", DbSchema);
                b.ConfigureByConvention();
    
                b.HasIndex(r => r.ResourceIdentifier).IsUnique();
                b.ApplyObjectExtensionMappings();
            });
    
            builder.Entity<CameraSession>(b =>
            {
                b.ToTable("WFT_CameraSessions", DbSchema);
                b.ConfigureByConvention();
    
                // Map this so that we're a json column for this structure
                b.OwnsOne(cs => cs.LprEvent, d =>
                {
                    d.ToJson();
                    d.OwnsOne(evt => evt.Data);
                });
                b.ApplyObjectExtensionMappings();
            });
        }
    
        private void ConfigureQuartzTables(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.AddQuartz(b => { b.UsePostgreSql(schema: DbSchema); });
        }
    }
```

---

And here is the entire test-module setup, for reference:


```
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;
using Serilog;
using Volo.Abp;
using Volo.Abp.Account;
using Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Volo.Abp.AuditLogging.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Volo.Abp.Authorization;
using Volo.Abp.Autofac;
using Volo.Abp.AutoMapper;
using Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs;
using Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Volo.Abp.BlobStoring.Database.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Volo.Abp.Caching;
using Volo.Abp.Data;
using Volo.Abp.Emailing;
using Volo.Abp.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Volo.Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite;
using Volo.Abp.FeatureManagement;
using Volo.Abp.FeatureManagement.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Volo.Abp.Identity;
using Volo.Abp.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Volo.Abp.Modularity;
using Volo.Abp.MultiTenancy;
using Volo.Abp.OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Volo.Abp.PermissionManagement;
using Volo.Abp.PermissionManagement.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Volo.Abp.SettingManagement;
using Volo.Abp.SettingManagement.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Volo.Abp.TenantManagement;
using Volo.Abp.TenantManagement.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Volo.Abp.Threading;
using Volo.Abp.Uow;
using WFT.CameraControl;
using WFT.CameraControl.Data;

namespace WFT.CameraControlTests.Base;

[DependsOn(
    typeof(AbpAutofacModule),
    typeof(AbpTestBaseModule),
    typeof(AbpAuthorizationModule),
    typeof(AbpBackgroundJobsAbstractionsModule),

    // ABP Framework packages
    typeof(AbpAutoMapperModule),
    typeof(AbpCachingModule),

    // Application
    typeof(AbpAccountApplicationModule),
    typeof(AbpAccountApplicationContractsModule),
    typeof(AbpPermissionManagementApplicationModule),
    typeof(AbpIdentityApplicationModule),
    typeof(AbpAccountApplicationModule),
    typeof(AbpTenantManagementApplicationModule),
    typeof(AbpSettingManagementApplicationModule),

    // EFCore
    typeof(AbpPermissionManagementEntityFrameworkCoreModule),
    typeof(AbpSettingManagementEntityFrameworkCoreModule),
    typeof(AbpBackgroundJobsEntityFrameworkCoreModule),
    typeof(AbpAuditLoggingEntityFrameworkCoreModule),
    typeof(AbpFeatureManagementEntityFrameworkCoreModule),
    typeof(AbpIdentityEntityFrameworkCoreModule),
    typeof(AbpOpenIddictEntityFrameworkCoreModule),
    typeof(AbpTenantManagementEntityFrameworkCoreModule),
    typeof(BlobStoringDatabaseEntityFrameworkCoreModule),
    typeof(AbpEntityFrameworkCoreSqliteModule)

    // For Background jobs, managed by Quartz
    // Fails if you run more than one test at a time, as it tries to instantiate many singleton Quartz schedulers
    // So for now, we'll just use the in-memory background job manager
    // typeof(AbpBackgroundJobsQuartzModule),
)]
public class CameraControlTestBaseModule : AbpModule
{
    /*
     * We have to replicate much of what the main App Module does
     * Because we can't depend on it in the test project (don't want all of it's HTTP imports)
     */
    public override void PreConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Async(c => c.Console())
            .CreateBootstrapLogger();

        // https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/release-notes/6.0.html#opting-out-of-the-new-timestamp-mapping-logic
        AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);

        PreConfigure<OpenIddictBuilder>(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddValidation(options =>
            {
                options.AddAudiences("CameraControl");
                options.UseLocalServer();
                options.UseAspNetCore();
            });
        });
        // PreConfigure<AbpAspNetCoreComponentsWebOptions>(options => { options.IsBlazorWebApp = true; });

        CameraControlGlobalFeatureConfigurator.Configure();
        CameraControlModuleExtensionConfigurator.Configure();
    }
    
   
    public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
    {
        // Turn off job execution...
        Configure<AbpBackgroundJobOptions>(options => { options.IsJobExecutionEnabled = false; });
        context.Services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IEmailSender, NullEmailSender>());
        context.Services.AddAlwaysAllowAuthorization();

        ConfigureMultiTenancy();
        ConfigureAutoMapper(context);
        ConfigureAutoApiControllers();
        ConfigureEfCore(context);

        // add in the assembly, which results in registering the services
        // this is so that all the services and repositories are registered, so we can use them in the test
        // var cameraControlAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(CameraControlAppService));
        // if (cameraControlAssembly != null) context.Services.AddAssembly(cameraControlAssembly);

        // EF Core
        Configure<FeatureManagementOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.SaveStaticFeaturesToDatabase = false;
            options.IsDynamicFeatureStoreEnabled = false;
        });
        Configure<PermissionManagementOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.SaveStaticPermissionsToDatabase = false;
            options.IsDynamicPermissionStoreEnabled = false;
        });
        context.Services.AddAlwaysDisableUnitOfWorkTransaction();

        ConfigureInMemorySqlite(context.Services);
    }

    private void ConfigureEfCore(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
    {
        // This should register the DbContext and the repositories
        context.Services.AddAbpDbContext<CameraControlDbContext>(options =>
        {
            /* create default repositories only for aggregate roots
             * Documentation: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Entity-Framework-Core#add-default-repositories
             */
            options.AddDefaultRepositories(includeAllEntities: true);
        });

        Configure<AbpDbContextOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Configure(configurationContext => { configurationContext.UseSqlite(options => { }); });
        });
    }

    private void ConfigureAutoApiControllers()
    {
        Configure<AbpAspNetCoreMvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ConventionalControllers.Create(typeof(CameraControlModule).Assembly);
        });
    }

    private void ConfigureMultiTenancy()
    {
        Configure<AbpMultiTenancyOptions>(options => { options.IsEnabled = CameraControlModule.IsMultiTenant; });
    }

    private void ConfigureAutoMapper(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
    {
        context.Services.AddAutoMapperObjectMapper<CameraControlModule>();
        Configure<AbpAutoMapperOptions>(options =>
        {
            /* Uncomment `validate: true` if you want to enable the Configuration Validation feature.
             * See AutoMapper's documentation to learn what it is:
             * https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration-validation.html
             */
            options.AddMaps<CameraControlModule>( /* validate: true */);
        });
    }


    public override void OnApplicationInitialization(ApplicationInitializationContext context)
    {
        SeedTestData(context);
    }

    private static void SeedTestData(ApplicationInitializationContext context)
    {
        AsyncHelper.RunSync(async () =>
        {
            using (var scope = context.ServiceProvider.CreateScope())
            {
                await scope.ServiceProvider
                    .GetRequiredService<IDataSeeder>()
                    .SeedAsync();
            }
        });
    }
    
    
    // In memory SQLLite DB Stuff
    public override void OnApplicationShutdown(ApplicationShutdownContext context)
    {
        _sqliteConnection?.Dispose();
    }
    
    private SqliteConnection? _sqliteConnection;

    private void ConfigureInMemorySqlite(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        _sqliteConnection = CreateDatabaseAndGetConnection();

        services.Configure<AbpDbContextOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Configure(context => { context.DbContextOptions.UseSqlite(_sqliteConnection); });
        });
    }
    private static SqliteConnection CreateDatabaseAndGetConnection()
    {
        var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=:memory:");
        connection.Open();

        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CameraControlDbContext>()
            .UseSqlite(connection)
            .Options;

        using (var context = new CameraControlDbContext(options))
        {
            context.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>().CreateTables();
        }

        return connection;
    }

}
```


